# Creating a Kernel with ImageProc

Tags: java, opencv

I'm using the following code to create a kernel and dilate using Python.

```
kernel = np.array([[0., 1., 0.], [1., 1., 1.], [0., 1., 0.]], np.uint8)
proc = cv2.dilate(proc, kernel)
```

How do I create the kernel with the same values while using ImageProc?

Comment: By tagging your python code with Java and C# you are inviting exactly the wrong kind of extra attention to your question.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch ImageProc Module is the same in both Java and c# so I tagged it that way. I have removed c# tag. :)